# Match the zone for each value based on some conditions

Tags: ruby, compare, match

I have this input table that shows the country codes and zones related with each Country Code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width=170 style='width:102.0pt;margin-left:-.05pt;border-collapse:collapse'>
  <tr style='height:.2in'>
    <td width=170 nowrap colspan=2 valign=bottom style='width:102.0pt;border:
  solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#BF8F00;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;
  height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><b><span style='color:black'>ZONES
  TABLE</span></b></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style='height:.2in'>
    <td width=122 style='width:73.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-top:
  none;background:#305496;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><b><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:white'>COUNTRY CODE</span></b></p>
    </td>
    <td width=48 style='width:29.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:
  solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#305496;
  padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><b><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:white'>ZONE</span></b></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style='height:.2in'>
    <td width=122 style='width:73.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-top:
  none;background:#FAFAFA;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>237</span></p>
    </td>
    <td width=48 style='width:29.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:
  solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#FAFAFA;
  padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>CMR</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style='height:.2in'>
    <td width=122 style='width:73.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-top:
  none;background:#FAFAFA;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>1721</span></p>
    </td>
    <td width=48 style='width:29.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:
  solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#FAFAFA;
  padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>SXM2</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style='height:.2in'>
    <td width=122 style='width:73.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-top:
  none;background:#FAFAFA;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>124622</span></p>
    </td>
    <td width=48 style='width:29.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:
  solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#FAFAFA;
  padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>BRB1</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style='height:.2in'>
    <td width=122 style='width:73.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-top:
  none;background:#FAFAFA;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>334</span></p>
    </td>
    <td width=48 style='width:29.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:
  solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#FAFAFA;
  padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>FRA3</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style='height:.2in'>
    <td width=122 style='width:73.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-top:
  none;background:#FAFAFA;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>124624</span></p>
    </td>
    <td width=48 style='width:29.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:
  solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#FAFAFA;
  padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>BRB3</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style='height:.2in'>
    <td width=122 style='width:73.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-top:
  none;background:#FAFAFA;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>124</span></p>
    </td>
    <td width=48 style='width:29.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:
  solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#FAFAFA;
  padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>BRB45</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style='height:.2in'>
    <td width=122 style='width:73.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-top:
  none;background:#FAFAFA;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>1246</span></p>
    </td>
    <td width=48 style='width:29.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:
  solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#FAFAFA;
  padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>BRB7</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style='height:.2in'>
    <td width=122 style='width:73.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-top:
  none;background:#FAFAFA;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>1876</span></p>
    </td>
    <td width=48 style='width:29.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:
  solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#FAFAFA;
  padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>JAM</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style='height:.2in'>
    <td width=122 style='width:73.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-top:
  none;background:#FAFAFA;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>358</span></p>
    </td>
    <td width=48 style='width:29.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:
  solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#FAFAFA;
  padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>FIN</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style='height:.2in'>
    <td width=122 style='width:73.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-top:
  none;background:#FAFAFA;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>33751</span></p>
    </td>
    <td width=48 style='width:29.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:
  solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#FAFAFA;
  padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>FRA1</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style='height:.2in'>
    <td width=122 style='width:73.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-top:
  none;background:#FAFAFA;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>33679</span></p>
    </td>
    <td width=48 style='width:29.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:
  solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#FAFAFA;
  padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>FRA2</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style='height:.2in'>
    <td width=122 style='width:73.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-top:
  none;background:#FAFAFA;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>599</span></p>
    </td>
    <td width=48 style='width:29.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:
  solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#FAFAFA;
  padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>ANT</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style='height:.2in'>
    <td width=122 style='width:73.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-top:
  none;background:#FAFAFA;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>61</span></p>
    </td>
    <td width=48 style='width:29.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:
  solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#FAFAFA;
  padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>AUS</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style='height:.2in'>
    <td width=122 style='width:73.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-top:
  none;background:#FAFAFA;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>230</span></p>
    </td>
    <td width=48 style='width:29.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:
  solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#FAFAFA;
  padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>MUS</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style='height:.2in'>
    <td width=122 style='width:73.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-top:
  none;background:#FAFAFA;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>31</span></p>
    </td>
    <td width=48 style='width:29.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:
  solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#FAFAFA;
  padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>NLD</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style='height:.2in'>
    <td width=122 style='width:73.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-top:
  none;background:#FAFAFA;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>65</span></p>
    </td>
    <td width=48 style='width:29.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:
  solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#FAFAFA;
  padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>SGP</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style='height:.2in'>
    <td width=122 style='width:73.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-top:
  none;background:#FAFAFA;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>1721</span></p>
    </td>
    <td width=48 style='width:29.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:
  solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#FAFAFA;
  padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>SXM4</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style='height:.2in'>
    <td width=122 style='width:73.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-top:
  none;background:#FAFAFA;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>1</span></p>
    </td>
    <td width=48 style='width:29.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:
  solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#FAFAFA;
  padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>USA</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style='height:.2in'>
    <td width=122 style='width:73.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-top:
  none;background:#FAFAFA;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>124623</span></p>
    </td>
    <td width=48 style='width:29.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:
  solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#FAFAFA;
  padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.2in'>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  text-align:center;line-height:normal'><span style='font-size:8.0pt;
  font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;color:black'>BRB2</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</html>
```

And I have the codes in column NUMBERS of the following table for which I want to search the corresponding ZONE from table above. In below Table the Column ZONE would be the Output I trying to get for the values in column NUMBERS.

```html
<style type="text/css">
 table.tableizer-table {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC; 
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 } 
 .tableizer-table td {
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
 }
 .tableizer-table th {
  background-color: #BF8F00; 
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
 }
.tableizer-table tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}     
  .tableizer-table tr:first-child td {
      background-color: #305496; color: #FFF;
    }
    tr td:nth-child(3) {
  background: #DFDFDF;
}
tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3) {
  background: #5D5B56;
}

</style>
<table class="tableizer-table">
<thead><tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th>NUMBERS to SEARCH</th><th>ZONE EXPECTED</th><th>&nbsp;</th></tr></thead><tbody>
 <tr><td>NUMBERS</td><td>ZONE</td><td>NOTES about logic to match the zone</td></tr>
 <tr><td>18763044</td><td>JAM</td><td>CC=1876 belongs to JAM</td></tr>
 <tr><td>187635</td><td>JAM</td><td>CC=1876 belongs to JAM</td></tr>
 <tr><td>23092</td><td>MUS</td><td>CC=230 belongs to JAM</td></tr>
 <tr><td>3162</td><td>NLD</td><td>CC=31 belongs to NLD</td></tr>
 <tr><td>38050</td><td>NOT FOUND</td><td>There is no CC that has as prefix 38,380, 3805 etc</td></tr>
 <tr><td>33</td><td>FRA3</td><td>There are 3 CC that begins with 33, but 334 selected because is the shortest and belongs to FRA3</td></tr>
 <tr><td>49185</td><td>NOT FOUND</td><td>There is no CC that begins with 49,491, etc</td></tr>
 <tr><td>51078</td><td>NOT FOUND</td><td>There is no CC that begins with 51,510, etc</td></tr>
 <tr><td>1246</td><td>BRB7</td><td>There are 4 CC that begins with 1246, but there is one exact match, CC=1246 that belongs to ZONE BRB7</td></tr>
 <tr><td>1721</td><td>SXM2</td><td>There are 2 CC that begins with 1721, but the ZONE to select is that that appears first. In this case SXM2</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

I've putted the tables values in arrays form and so far I have the code below that detects with values of array cc begins with values in numbers, but the output is far
from my expected output, since I not sure how to do it. May be someone could help me. Thanks in advance.

```
cc=["237","1721","124622","334","124624","124","1246","1876","358","33751","33679","599","61","230","31","65","1721","1","124623"]
zones=["CMR","SXM2","BRB1","FRA3","BRB3","BRB45","BRB7","JAM","FIN","FRA1","FRA2","ANT","AUS","MUS","NLD","SGP","SXM4","USA","BRB2"]
numbers=["18763044","187635","23092","3162","38050","33","49185","51078","1246","1721"]

numbers.map{|n| 
    cc.find {|i|  i.start_with?(n) }
}

=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, "334", nil, nil, "124622", "1721"]
```

Comment: @iGian 
The expected output are the Zones in column ZONE on second snippet. The 3rd column on second snippet is only an explanation of the logic needed to apply in different conditions to match the more similar country code to each value in column NUMBERS. I show the snippets to try to make easier to understand

Comment: @iGian For some reason I missed to put the first value 237 in array cc. If you see the first snippet you'll see that cc and zones have the same size. I've modified cc array.

Comment: @iGian Hi iGian. The reason why 1 (USA) is never selected is because 1 is not part of the column NUMBERS, so 1 is not one of the numbers to find. I'm not sure if that answers your doubt. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completely changed the answer after some clarifications, this is what I did so far. Passible of optimisation.

---

First thing a method to count how many elements matches starting from the beginning. It works only with strings of numbers:

```
def count_equal_digits_at_beginning(a, b)
  return a.size if a == b
  rabdiff = (a.reverse.to_i - b.reverse.to_i).abs
  rabdiff.digits.count - rabdiff.to_s.reverse.to_i.digits.count
end
```

---

Second, map the pairs `[cc, zones]` to an hash, for rapid and easy access. I reversed, because the requirement is to keep the first appearance of the key:

```
mapping_hash = cc.reverse.zip(zones.reverse).to_h
```

---

Finally write a code that looks form matches, filters and sorts the result and pick up from the `mapping_hash`. (Edited to give precedence to exact match and ascending order)

```
res = numbers.map.with_object([]) do |n, res|
  exact = cc.find { |c| c == n }
  if exact
    found = exact
  else
    tmp = cc.map { |c| [c, count_equal_digits_at_beginning(c, n)] }
    possibles = tmp.find_all { |c, count| count == tmp.max_by(&:last).last && count > 1 }
    good = possibles.sort_by(&:first).reverse.first
    found = good.first if good
  end
  res << [ n, mapping_hash[found] || "not found" ]
end.to_h
```

So, the final result is

```
res #=> {"18763044"=>"JAM", "187635"=>"JAM", "23092"=>"MUS", "3162"=>"NLD", "38050"=>"not found", "33"=>"FRA1", "49185"=>"not found", "51078"=>"not found", "1246"=>"BRB7", "1721"=>"SXM2"}
```

Comment: `But you pick 1876 from cc not because it starts with 18763044, but for the opposite reason. So why not USA, since in numbers a lot of elements start with "1"?` Here is selected 1876 because the goal is to match the most similar value between NIMBERS and COUNTRY CODE.

Comment: In that case the number selected supposing there is no exact match should be the first with shortest lenght and the zone to select would be the first sorting ascending. For example: for the value 1246, `"1246"=>[["124622", "BRB1"], ["124624222", "BRB3"], ["124", "BRB45"], ["1", "USA"], ["12465", "BRB2"]]` the value to select should be `12465` (is the shortest value that contains the prefix 1246).  If no exact match but all values have the same length then select the first value in ascending order and its corresponding zone. For these values `124632,124642,124609,124673` select `124609`

Comment: Hi iGian. When I try the last block of code `res = numbers.map.....end.to_h`  receive the following error. ` undefined method `digits' for 44036049:Fixnum` Does it happen for you either?

Comment: I see this alternative in the link you shared `25.to_s.each_char {|c| print c, ' ' }` but where/how within the block `res` could be replaced this method instead of `digits`?

Comment: Excellent iGian. It seems to work pretty fine in my Ruby version changing `digits` for that alternative code. One more thing. I was wondering if you could help me to modify one part of the logic in your code. For example for NUMBER `33` there 3 values that begin with 33 in array CC (334/FRA3,33751/FRA1 and 33679/FRA2). Then would be possible for you in this kind of cases, instead to select the shortest value (334/FRA3), select the ZONE that is the first sorted ascending, for this case for 33 the match would be `33751/FRA1` instead of `334/FRA3` . Thanks again

Comment: @GerCas I made an edit to take in account the exact match. Please, consider to clean up comments (maybe moving the most relevant into your answer).

Comment: Thanks so much for you help iGian. Very appreciated